# Casting a Session variable as an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have a list that is converted to an array then put into a session
so in another page i would access to that array but when I'm trying to unbox it, it would not return a correct value

```
//codes from page one :
List<string> seatNum = new List<string>();
string[] seatnumArray = new string[ordered]; //Ordered is a defined int variable
seatnumArray = seatNum.ToArray();

//codes from page two :
if (Session["SeatNum"] != null){
    lblseatname.Text = Session["SeatNum"].ToString();
}

//Output view :
System.String[]
```

Comment: `Unboxing` is not the right terminology for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the Session object back to a List

```
List<string> seatNumFromSession = Session["SeatNum"] as List<string>;
```

Then you can use it again as you would any other List.

```
lblseatname.Text = seatNumFromSession[0];
```

Comment: it returns an Exception (Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Comment: It worked it was a problem from page one that i converted a list into an array

Answer (score 0):

It worked it was a problem from page one that i converted a list into an array 
`

```
`//codes from page one :
    List<string> seatNum = new List<string>();
    string[] seatnumArray = new string[ordered]; //Ordered is a defined int variable
 //codes from page two :
    List<string> seatNumFromSession = Session["SeatNum"] as List<string>;
    lblseatname.Text = seatNumFromSession[0];
```